# how to subtract 12 hours 30 minutes from the MySQL from date field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I have reduce or subtract 12 hours 30 minutes from the 2011-04-26 05:00:00(in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) IN MySQL database.

The output should be 2011-04-25 16:30:00.

Are there any date function we can use and subtract?

Answer (score 9):

```
DATE_SUB(`date`,INTERVAL '12:30' HOUR_MINUTE)
```

Checkout [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) of mysql

Answer (score 6):

```
select '2011-04-26 05:00:00' - interval 12 * 60 + 30 minute
```

Answer (score 3):

The date/time functions are documented here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

You probably want [DATE_SUB()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub).

Answer (score 0):

Fine, This can be done by  **DATE_ADD()** function in MySQL

```
select lastname, 
        changedat, date_add(changedat, interval - '12:30' hour) as newdate
    from employee_audit;
```

**lastname** and **changedat** is field name and **employee_audit** is table name.

[image]